# How to put django forms in order?

Tags: django, summernote

I am trying to add summernote to my website but it appears that it messed up my forms.

I want the title to be first, image_url to be second, and text to be last.

Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

**Forms**

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectPost
        fields = {'title', 'image_url', 'text'}
        widgets = {
            'text': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
        }
```

**models**

```
class ProjectPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2):

Fields are rendered in the order they are defined in the meta class's `fields` attribute.

For some reason, you have defined these fields as a *set* `{'title', 'image_url', 'text'}` which is an unordered collection, which is why your fields are not rendering as you like.

Change the fields attribute to an ordered collection, like a list or a tuple and your problem should be solved:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = ProjectPost
    fields = ['title', 'image_url', 'text']
    widgets = {
        'text': SummernoteInplaceWidget(),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fields in your **form.py** are in the correct order you should check your **html**:

```
<form>
    {{form.text}}
    {{form.image_url}}
    {{form.title}}
</form>
```

And replace it with:

```
<form>
    {{form.title}}
    {{form.image_url}}
    {{form.text}}
</form>
```